# Упростить и усовершенствовать код игрушки "угадай число"

Tags: python, инспекция-кода

Составил небольшой код игрушки "угадай число"
Можете подсказать, как упростить код, и что можно добавить

```
import math
import os
from random import randint
import sys
l =1 
checkminran = False
checkmaxran = False
x = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
print("Давай сыграем с тобой в игру угадай число, для начала выбери диапазон случайного числа")
#Проверка диап случ числа:
while l == 1:
    while checkminran == False:
        try:
            minran =int((input("минимальное число:")))
            checkminran = True
        except ValueError:   
            print('Это не является целым чесло, попробуй еще ')  
    while checkmaxran == False:
        try:
            maxran =int((input("максимальное число:")))
            checkmaxran = True
        except ValueError:   
            print('Это не является целым чесло, попробуй еще ')  
    if minran > maxran:
        ran = randint(maxran,minran)
        matt = int((minran-maxran+1)/2)
        veb1=0
        l = 0
    elif maxran > minran:
        ran = randint(minran,maxran)
        matt =int((maxran-minran+1)/2)
        veb1=1
        l=0
    else:
        print("Это безпройграшный вариант, так не честно")
        checkminran=False
        checkmaxran=False

if matt > 1:
    print ("теперь укажи желаемое кол-во попыток(кол-во попыток должно быть меньше или равно "+str(matt)+")")
    print('Если не знаешь, какое хочешь кол-во попыток, можешь довериться везению и ввести "0"')
    i = False
    #выбор кол-во попыток:
    while i == False:
        try:
            att = int(input())
            if att == 0:
                att=randint(1,matt)
                i=True
            elif att > matt:
                print("Слишком много попыток, это не честно, возьмите меньше попыток")
            else:
                i=True
        except ValueError:   
            print('Это не является целым чесло, попробуй еще ')  
else:
    att = 1
if att == 1:
    x = "ка"
elif att == 2 or att == 3 or att == 4:
    x = "ки"
else:
    x = "ок"
print ("У тебя есть "+str(att)+" попыт"+x+", чтобы угадать заданное случайное число то "+str(minran)+" до "+str(maxran)+"")
checkyourint = False
while checkyourint == False:
    try:
        yourint = int (input())
        checkyourint = True
    except ValueError:   
            print('Это не является целым чесло, попробуй еще ')  

checkyourint = False
#Сама игра:

while checkyourint == False:
    while att > 0:
        checkyourint = False
        if yourint == ran:
            print ("ты выиграл")
            att = att-att
            exit = int(input('Введите "1", если хотите сыграть еще раз, если нет: введите что угодно:'))
            if exit == 1:
                os.execv(sys.executable, ['python'] + sys.argv)
            else:
                break
            
        elif yourint < ran:
            att = att-1
            if att == 1:
                x = "ка"
            elif att == 2 or att == 3 or att == 4:
                x = "ки"
            else:
                x = "ок"
            print ("неверно, твое число меньше загадонного, у тебя осталось "+str(att)+" попыт"+x)
            
            if att ==0:
                print ("ты проиграл, число было: "+str(ran))
                att = att-att
                exit = int(input('Введите "1", если хотите сыграть еще раз, если нет: введите что угодно:'))
                if exit == 1:
                    os.execv(sys.executable, ['python'] + sys.argv)
                else:
                    break
            checkyourint = False
            while checkyourint == False:
                try:
                    yourint = int (input())
                    checkyourint = True
                except ValueError:   
                        print('Это не является целым чесло, попробуй еще ')  
        elif yourint > ran:
            att = att-1
            if att == 1:
                x = "ка"
            elif att == 2 or att == 3 or att == 4:
                x = "ки"
            else:
                x = "ок"
            print ("неверно, твое число больше загадонного, у тебя осталось "+str(att)+" попыт"+x)
            if att ==0:
                print ("ты проиграл, было число: "+str(ran))
                att = att-att
                exit = int(input('Введите "1", если хотите сыграть еще раз, если нет: введите что угодно:'))
                if exit == 1:
                    os.execv(sys.executable, ['python'] + sys.argv)
                else:
                    break
            checkyourint = False
            while checkyourint == False:
                try:
                    yourint = int (input())
                    checkyourint = True
                except ValueError:   
                        print('Это не является целым чесло, попробуй еще ')
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Используйте [`f-строки`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html?highlight=formatting#tut-f-strings).
2. Используйте [функции](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).
3. Для склонений используйте словарь (я назвал его `declinations`).
4. Не меняйте "ты" на "вы" в течение общения с пользователем. Придерживайтесь одного выбранного варианта.

Вот как-то так:

```
from random import randint

declinations = {
    0: 'попыток',
    1: 'попытка',
    2: 'попытки',
    3: 'попытки',
    # дальше сами
    5: ...,
    6: ...,
    7: ...,
    8: ...,
    9: ...,
    # а дальше уже заполнять не нужно
}

def get_int(out='', err='Это не целое число. Попробуйте еще раз.'):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(out))
        except ValueError:
            print(err)

def get_range_min_max():
    while True: 
        min_num = get_int(out='Минимальное число:')
        max_num = get_int(out='Максимальное число:')
        if min_num == max_num:
            print('Так не честно!')
        else:
            return sorted((min_num, max_num))

def get_attempts(min_num, max_num):
    diff = (max_num-min_num+1)//2
    if diff <= 1:
        return 1

    print(f'Укажите желаемое кол-во попыток (кол-во попыток должно быть меньше или равно {matt})')
    print('Если не знаете, какое хотите кол-во попыток, можете довериться везению и ввести "0"')
    while True:
        attempts = get_int('Введите кол-во попыток:')
        if attempts > diff:
            print('Слишком много попыток, возьмите меньше попыток.')
        else:
            return attempts

def guess_game():
    while attempts:
        attempts -= 1
        declination = declination.get(attempts%10)
        answer = get_int('Ваша попытка:')!
        if answer==num_to_guess:
            print('Вы победили!')
            break
        elif answer < num_to_guess:
            print(f'Ваше число меньше загаданного. У вас осталось {attempts} {declination}.')
        else:
            print(f'Ваше число больше загаданного. У вас осталось {attempts} {declination}.')
    else:
        print('Попытки кончились.')
        print(f'Я загадывал число {num_to_guess}.')

while True: # main game cycle
    # getting minimum and maximum of the range
    min_num, max_num = get_range_min_max()
    # randomising number to guess
    num_to_guess = randint(min_num, max_num)
    # selecting the number of attempts
    attempts = get_attempts(min_num, max_num)
    declination = declination.get(attempts%10)
    print(f'У вас есть {attempts} {declination}, чтобы угадать число от {min_num} по {max_num}.')
    # guessing cycle
    guess_game()
    # do user want to play again ?
    if input('Введите 1, если хотите сыграть еще раз. Иначе нажмите Enter.') != '1':
        break
```

Comment: а что если человек выберет больше 9ти попыток?

Comment: А что обозначает "def"?

Comment: Ну это не Вам задача была, а Автору вопроса :)

Comment: @Виктор, я автор вопроса :)

Comment: Я писал @n1tr0xs - он за Вас порешал, я хотел, чтобы у Вас появился навык использования функций - def

Comment: @ЕгорКольцов не важно сколько попыток будет выбрано `str(attempts)[-1]` / `attempts%10` вернет последнюю цифру числа, а она всегда одна. `def` - функция.

Answer (score 0):

Начните с изучения возможностей python. Функции, циклы, выход из циклов....

Полезно почитать про f-строки для формирования строк

Вот пример для изучения (на базе Вашего кода):

```
def getInt(str = ''): # Функция чтения int из stdin
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(str)) # Возвращаем int
        except ValueError:   
            print('Это не является целым числом, попробуй еще')

minran = getInt("минимальное число:")
maxran = getInt("максимальное число:")
```

В аналогичном ключе поменяйте Ваши запросы ввода целых чисел и код будет несколько легче понимать и не будет повторов одного и тогоже кода.

Ну и это зачем? os.execv(sys.executable, ['python'] + sys.argv)

У Вас же циклы для этого есть, чтобы начать игру с самого начала.

Comment: Я искал как можно вписать строчку, для перезапуска кода, и нашел это

Comment: Поправьте код, с использованием функции в ответе, и Вам лучше будет видно, как организовать запуск игры снова, без повторного запуска программы. Как поправите код, измените на новый в вопросе (Править). И дальше будем смотреть

Answer (score 0):

Максимально простой вариант.

```
    from random import randint
    i=randint(1,10)
    print ("Случайное число от 1 до 10 сгенерировано, попробуй угадать!")
    o=int(input("Введите предполагаемое число: "))
    if i == o:
        print ("Вы угадали, это число: " + str(i))
    else:
        print ("Вы не угадали, это число: " + str(i))
```